# Docking Windows Phone controls to the bottom of a StackPanel

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to dock a Windows Phone control to the bottom of a StackPanel?  This is my basic layout:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <TextBlock />
  <TextBlock />
  <UI:AdControl />
</StackPanel>
```

My StackPanel is filling up the whole window.  The TextBlocks are aligned toward the top of the panel, that's what I want.

But I want the AdControl to dock at the bottom of the StackPanel (and therefore the bottom of the window).

I've found controls like DockPanel, but they seem to only work for WPF or Silverlight as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished with a simple grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock />
    </StackPanel>
    <UI:AdControl Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want exactly DockPanel for future use, make sure you look into open source implementations, there should be plenty of those out there!

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  The lesson I'm learning with StackPanel problems is "use the Grid instead."  :)

Comment: @ChadSC Every panel has its use. :) Don't forget to mark my answer as answer to your question since it helped you so it can help others in the future.